# Where can I find the apc extension for PHP 5.2.8 in windows?

Tags: php, windows, apc

I know it's not the latest version, but need to stick to it for the project.

Anyone knows where I can get apc extension for php 5.2.8?

Answer (score 0):

From [Pierre's extensions download page](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).

Comment: @wamp look harder, it's near the top. All that's there is for windows.

Comment: for the record:  I found that the version 3.1.4 of APC does not work correctly with windows (windows 7/apache 2) because it (for some strange reason) delete some stored values almost at random.  For example, i tried the next code :  $arreglo["login"]=$login;
 $arreglo["clave"]=$clave;
 $arreglo["nombre"]=$nombre;
 $arreglo["nivel"]=$nivel;
 apc_store("mystore",$arreglo);  and it works sometimes, while other times it store a false value.  So, be careful, this bug is extremely hard to spot.